# Clearing an OpenCL buffer using an Imagination IMG GPU

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I can successfully clear an OpenCL buffer object using `clEnqueueFillBuffer()` on Intel, NVIDIA, and AMD GPUs.

When I try to do the same on a Imagination IMG GPU, my program segfaults.

It could possibly be a driver bug, or it could be that I am not aware of all conditions that you can fill a buffer.

I allocate my buffer using:

```
mem_p32 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY, p32maxsz, NULL, &err);
```

I clear my buffer using:

```
static void clear_p32( int streamnr, int textotal )
{       
        static uint32_t val=0;
        const size_t sz = textotal * 3 * sizeof(uint32_t);
        cl_int err;
        err = clEnqueueFillBuffer(queues[streamnr], mem_p32, &val, 1, 0, sz, 0,0,0);
        CHECK_CL
}
```

How can I clear a buffer in a manner that works on all platforms?

Things that I have verified:

- I can't find a specific clear operation in the OpenCL API, so it looks like the Fill operation is the proper way to clear.
- I do not exceed the size of the buffer when clearing. As a matter of fact, the memset operation segfaults on the first location of the range. It even crashes when I clear just 1 byte.
- Using gdb gives little info, as there are no debug symbols in libPVROCL.so present, see below.

gdb session:

```
Thread 2 "testgib" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x3ff427e160 (LWP 15507)]
__GI_memset (dstpp=0x3fe8e7e000, c=0, len=<optimized out>) at ./string/memset.c:56
56  ./string/memset.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) where
#0  __GI_memset (dstpp=0x3fe8e7e000, c=0, len=<optimized out>) at ./string/memset.c:56
#1  0x0000003ff7aef292 in ?? () from /lib/libPVROCL.so
```

**OpenCL device**: PowerVR B-Series BXM-4-64 Imagination Technologies with [1 units] localmem=4KiB globalmem=5015MiB dims=3(512x512x512) max workgrp sz 512 fp16=y align=1024

**OS**: Debian GNU/Linux 12

**Hardware**: Sipeed Pi4A.

**Architecture:** RISCV

**SOC:** TH1520

Comment: It's a guess but try uint8_t val=0;

Comment: @SimonGoater Same result with uint8_t

Comment: A few thoughts, but don't really know what's going on here. Does clinfo run successfully on your Imagination GPU? If you take out all the code and make a minimal OpenCL program that only does the things it has to do to get to the clEnqueueFillBuffer() call, does it still fail in the same way? Have you confirmed that the Imagination OpenCL Platform version you're using is compatible with the OS you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess,you are using CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY,it means the device can read & wirte but host is read only,so when you tring fill this buffer from host, i don't know what AMD or Nvidia does but PowerVR seems give you a crash~

Comment: I'm not familier with OpenCL, maybe you can create buffer with CL_MEM_HOST_READ_WRITE?